# Is there a "Force Index" equivalent in Vertica?

Tags: mysql, vertica

Is there a "Force Index" from MySQL equivalent in Vertica DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select directly from a projection instead of the table.  For instance, instead of

```
select col from foo;
```

do this:

```
select col from foo_p1;  -- where table_p1 is a projection of table foo`
```

Comment: Just wanted to confirm this answer.

Comment: I'd add that a "table" is a projection too, but with all columns. All data that vertica have stored in projections.

Comment: tables in vertica are logical and not a physical term. The closes thing to a table in vertica is the initial super projection (which would contain all columns) in raw state.